# Mesh current analysis - with AC in s-domain

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, ac, homework, mesh-analysis

I have the following problem:

> Consider the circuit below, with
>
> - \$v_1(t)=5\text{V} \ \sin(\omega_0t)\$
> - \$v_2(t)=1.2\text{V} \, \cos(\omega_0t)\$
> - \$V_3=9 \text{V}\$
> - \$i_s(t)=0.5\text{A} \, \cos(\omega_0t+50^\circ)\$
>
> [image]
>
> The bottom of the arrow indicates the \$+\$-pole of each voltage source.
>
> At \$f_0 = 1.25 \text{MHz}\$ the circuit is in steady state.
>
> What is \$ |\mathbf{I_{out}}(s)| \$ at \$ f_0\$?
>
> What is the phase of \$ \mathbf{I_{out}}(s)\$ at \$f_0\$ referenced to \$ \mathbf{V_2}\$?

**EDIT**

I tried to simulate with LT spice and got the following result:

[image]

But I cannot confirm if what I'm getting is a correct result. That is why I would really like some help with this problem.

Comment: Are you assuming that the voltage across the current source is zero? If so, why?

Comment: Oh you are right, there is no reason that there shouldn't be a voltage drop across the current source. I will call that voltage drop \$v_s\$ and edit the question.

Comment: The Kirchhoff voltage law states that the sum of the voltages around a loop is zero.  The current law states that the sum of the currents into a node is zero.  Maybe you should begin by marking the loops as voltages.  Also mark the currents of all the sources as a starting point - calculating the current in L3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up the voltages wrong: for `V1` it should be `AC 5` because it's a sine, thus zero phase shift, for `V2` it should be `AC 1.2 90` (cosine), `V3` is correct, and `I1` should be `AC 0.5 140` (= 90 + 50). With these changes, I get these results:

[image: test]

I have also explicitly zeroed out all the parasitics for inductances and capacitors, since they could be influencing the result.

---

I've also ran a `.TRAN` analysis, as @VerbalKint's coment, and got these results:

[image: test]

The magnitude isn't exactly as in `.AC`, but I attribute that to the finite timestep and the differences between the way `.AC` is calculated behind the scene. The phase agrees, though.

Comment: Oh, I actually thought that the "small signal AC analysis" was cosine, but now I know better! I hope that \$ \mathbf{I}_{out}(s)=0.594A\$ and that \$ \angle \mathbf{I}_{out}(s) = -133.71^\circ \$, because the fact that my instructor wanted the answer in the s-domain really confused me. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @Carl Internally, yes (even if the results are complex), but when you set up a sine source, it has zero phase shift, so then the `.AC` phase should be zero.

Comment: I've never tried to run ac analyses at a single frequency with different active ac sources. If I use transient generators with adjusted delays for sin and cos waveforms, I find an rms current around 760 mA with a 63° phase shift with respect to \$V_2\$.

Comment: @VerbalKint I just recreated the schematic and ran it with 1k points over 125kHz...12.5MHz, and the readings are `594.66835`mA and `-133.71411`deg with the cursor spot on 1.25MHz. Then I tried `.TRAN` and got `0.594648`V and `-133.715`deg (with `.MEAS`). I have to say you gave me quite a scare. Maybe you're using -cos, instead of cos (delay of 90 deg, plus)? Or maybe you are reading `I(V2)` (as seen in the picture)? I'll update my answer to reflect my method.

Comment: @a concerned citizen, I had the wrong delay polarity on the cos sources. Once adjusted properly, I read 419.53 mA rms which translates to 593.3 mA peak and the signal is delayed by 136° with respect to \$V_2\$ so I confirm your numbers : )

Comment: @VerbalKint Those would be LTspice's, not mine. I merely pointed the finger and said "do it!"...

Comment: You mean like in the sorcerer's apprentice? : )

Comment: @VerbalKint Oh, no (I had to search for it to find out), I thought I'd try to conjure up the image of a tyrannical boss, but I failed. Maybe there's a message in there, somewhere? :-)

Comment: @a concerned citizen, Alright, just to be 100% sure. The phase is \$ -133.71^\circ\$ with respect to \$V_2\$ right?

Comment: @Carl No, that phase if for `I(V4)`, alone (see the readings). You mean it referenced to the *current* through `V2`, not the *voltage* across, right (rather absurd, but just to be sure, I've heard worse)? I'll assume the former (if no, it's just as easy), in which case it's a very simple subtraction: \$I(V_2)=473.306\rm{mA}\angle-152.013^o\$ (as seen in the picture above) \$=> -152.013-(-133.714)=18.299\$.

Comment: Ahh okay I see how it works now. Thank you for your very professional answer (as usual).

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's solve this mathematically. We have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnBWQI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_6}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_6}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_5}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_7}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_7-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_8}\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_9}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, we also know that \$\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2=\text{V}_\text{z}\$.

I used Mathematica to solve your problem. The code is used is:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Vz == V3 - V2, I1 == I4 + I5, I3 == I2 + I4, I8 == Ik + I5, 
   I8 == Ik + I7, I6 == I3 + I7, I6 == I1 + I2, I1 == (Vx - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (Vy - V1)/R2, I3 == (V6)/R3, I3 == (V5 - V6)/R4, 
   I3 == (V3 - V5)/R5, I6 == (V1 - V2)/R6, I7 == (V3 - V7)/R7, 
   I7 == (V7 - V4)/R8, I8 == (V4)/R9}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, 
   I8, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (-Ik R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R9 + (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + 
         R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) (Vx - Vy) + 
      R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) (Vx + Vz))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 +
          R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  I2 -> (-Ik R1 (R3 + R4 + R5) R9 - R4 R6 Vx - R5 R6 Vx - R4 R7 Vx - 
      R5 R7 Vx - R6 R7 Vx - R4 R8 Vx - R5 R8 Vx - R6 R8 Vx - 
      R4 R9 Vx - R5 R9 Vx - R6 R9 Vx - 
      R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) (Vx - Vy) + R1 R3 Vy + R1 R4 Vy + 
      R1 R5 Vy + R4 R6 Vy + R5 R6 Vy + R1 R7 Vy + R4 R7 Vy + 
      R5 R7 Vy + R6 R7 Vy + R1 R8 Vy + R4 R8 Vy + R5 R8 Vy + 
      R6 R8 Vy + R1 R9 Vy + R4 R9 Vy + R5 R9 Vy + R6 R9 Vy + 
      R1 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) Vz)/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  I3 -> (Ik (R2 R6 + R1 (R2 + R6)) R9 + (R7 + R8 + R9) (R2 (Vx + Vz) +
          R1 (Vy + Vz)))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + 
         R4 R8 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  I4 -> (Ik (R2 R6 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5 + R6)) R9 + R4 R6 Vx + 
      R5 R6 Vx + R2 R7 Vx + R4 R7 Vx + R5 R7 Vx + R6 R7 Vx + 
      R2 R8 Vx + R4 R8 Vx + R5 R8 Vx + R6 R8 Vx + R2 R9 Vx + 
      R4 R9 Vx + R5 R9 Vx + R6 R9 Vx + 
      R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) (Vx - Vy) - R1 R4 Vy - R1 R5 Vy - 
      R4 R6 Vy - R5 R6 Vy - R4 R7 Vy - R5 R7 Vy - R6 R7 Vy - 
      R4 R8 Vy - R5 R8 Vy - R6 R8 Vy - R4 R9 Vy - R5 R9 Vy - 
      R6 R9 Vy - R1 (R4 + R5) Vz + R2 (R7 + R8 + R9) Vz - 
      R1 R3 (Vy + Vz))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + 
         R4 R8 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  I5 -> (-Ik (R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R6) + 
         R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5 + R6)) R9 + (R3 + R4 + 
         R5) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz)))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  I6 -> (-Ik (R1 + R2) (R3 + R4 + R5) R9 + (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + 
         R9) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz)))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  I7 -> (-Ik (R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R6) + 
         R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5 + R6)) R9 + (R3 + R4 + 
         R5) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz)))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  I8 -> (Ik (R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + R4 R7 + R5 R7 + 
            R6 R7 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R8 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8) + 
            R3 (R6 + R7 + R8)) + 
         R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + (R5 + R6) R8 + 
            R3 (R6 + R7 + R8) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8))) + (R3 + R4 + 
         R5) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz)))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  V1 -> (Ik R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R9 + (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 +
          R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + 
         R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) (R2 Vx + R1 Vy) - 
      R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) Vz)/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  V2 -> -Vz + ((R3 + R4 + 
         R5) (Ik (R2 R6 + R1 (R2 + R6)) R9 + (R7 + R8 + 
            R9) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz))))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
          R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
          R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
          R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) +
        R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
          R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  V3 -> ((R3 + R4 + 
        R5) (Ik (R2 R6 + R1 (R2 + R6)) R9 + (R7 + R8 + 
           R9) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz))))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  V4 -> (R9 (Ik (R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + R4 R7 + R5 R7 + 
              R6 R7 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R8 + 
              R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8)) + 
           R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + (R5 + R6) R8 + 
              R3 (R6 + R7 + R8) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8))) + (R3 + R4 + 
           R5) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz))))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  V5 -> ((R3 + 
        R4) (Ik (R2 R6 + R1 (R2 + R6)) R9 + (R7 + R8 + 
           R9) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz))))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  V6 -> (R3 (Ik (R2 R6 + R1 (R2 + R6)) R9 + (R7 + R8 + 
           R9) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz))))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9))), 
  V7 -> (Ik ((R3 + R4 + R5) (R2 R6 + 
            R1 (R2 + R6)) + (R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R6) + 
            R1 (R2 + R3 + R4 + R5 + R6)) R7) R9 + (R3 + R4 + R5) (R8 +
          R9) (R2 (Vx + Vz) + R1 (Vy + Vz)))/(R1 (R4 R6 + R5 R6 + 
         R4 R7 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R4 R8 + R5 R8 + 
         R6 R8 + (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)) + 
      R2 (R5 R6 + R5 R7 + R6 R7 + R5 R8 + R6 R8 + (R5 + R6) R9 + 
         R3 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9) + R4 (R6 + R7 + R8 + R9)))}}
```

Now, applying your given values we get:

```
In[2]:=R1 = 1/(s*30*10^(-9));
R2 = s*360*10^(-9);
R3 = 18/10;
R4 = 1/(s*27*10^(-9));
R5 = s*(9/10)*10^(-6);
R6 = 3/10;
R7 = 1/(s*100*10^(-9));
R8 = 100*10^(-3);
R9 = s*100*10^(-9);
Vx = LaplaceTransform[5*Sin[\[Omega]0*t], t, s];
Vy = LaplaceTransform[(12/10)*Cos[\[Omega]0*t], t, s];
Vz = LaplaceTransform[9, t, s];
Ik = LaplaceTransform[(1/2)*Cos[\[Omega]0*t + (50*(Pi/180))], t, s];
\[Omega]0 = 2*Pi*f0;
f0 = (125/100)*10^6;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Vz == V3 - V2, I1 == I4 + I5, I3 == I2 + I4, I8 == Ik + I5, 
   I8 == Ik + I7, I6 == I3 + I7, I6 == I1 + I2, I1 == (Vx - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (Vy - V1)/R2, I3 == (V6)/R3, I3 == (V5 - V6)/R4, 
   I3 == (V3 - V5)/R5, I6 == (V1 - V2)/R6, I7 == (V3 - V7)/R7, 
   I7 == (V7 - V4)/R8, I8 == (V4)/R9}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, 
   I8, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7}]]

Out[2]={{I1 -> (60000000 s (31250000000000000000000000000000000000 \[Pi] + 
         625000000000000000000000000 (-4800 + \[Pi] (4835 + 
               10287 \[Pi])) s + 
         6250000000000000000 (-46416 + \[Pi] (410225 + 
               41553 \[Pi])) s^2 + 
         18750000000000 (49052 + 27 \[Pi] (209 + 270 \[Pi])) s^3 + 
         60750000 (608 + 625 \[Pi]) s^4 + 21141 s^5) + 
      67500000 \[Pi] s^4 (10000000000000000 + 
         243 s (2000000 + s)) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] - 
      27 s^5 (10000000000000000 + 243 s (2000000 + s)) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
        9])/(2 (6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  I2 -> (10000000 (3 (595312500000000000000000000000000000000000000 \
\[Pi]^2 + 
           15625000000000000000000000000000000 \[Pi] (-2000 + 
              1539 \[Pi]) s + 
           3125000000000000000000000000 (35504 + \[Pi] (-967 + 
                 4050 \[Pi])) s^2 - 
           6250000000000000000 (-744096 + 181625 \[Pi]) s^3 - 
           356250000000000 (-6748 + 135 \[Pi]) s^4 - 
           60750000 (-76 + 125 \[Pi]) s^5 + 729 s^6) + 
        312500000000000 \[Pi] s^2 (10000000000000000 + 
           243 s (2000000 + s)) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] - 
        125000000 s^3 (10000000000000000 + 243 s (2000000 + s)) Sin[(
          2 \[Pi])/9]))/((6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  I3 -> (40500000 (20 (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
           6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
           112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (100000000000000 + 
           s (1000000 + s)) - 
        2500000 \[Pi] s^3 (2500000000000000 + 
           3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] + 
        s^4 (2500000000000000 + 3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
          9]))/((6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  I4 -> (500000 (120 (-234375000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \
\[Pi]^2 - 
           15625000000000000000000000000000000 \[Pi] (-1000 + 
              729 \[Pi]) s - 
           312500000000000000000000000 (140800 + \[Pi] (-4835 + 
                 16038 \[Pi])) s^2 + 
           3125000000000000000 (-707376 + \[Pi] (230225 + 
                 2187 \[Pi])) s^3 + 
           9375000000000 (-104308 + 27 \[Pi] (101 + 27 \[Pi])) s^4 + 
           151875000 (-8 + 35 \[Pi]) s^5 + 729 s^6) - 
        2500000 \[Pi] s^2 (25000000000000000000000000 + 
           81 s (17500000000000000 + 3 s (3500000000 + 9 s))) Cos[(
          2 \[Pi])/9] + 
        s^3 (25000000000000000000000000 + 
           81 s (17500000000000000 + 3 s (3500000000 + 9 s))) Sin[(
          2 \[Pi])/9]))/((6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  I5 -> (60000000 (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
         6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
         112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (10000000000000000 + 
         243 s (2000000 + s)) + 
      2500000 \[Pi] s^2 (25000000000000000000000000000000 + 
         27 s (52500000000000000000000 + 
            s (41500000000000000 + 81 s (7000000 + 3 s)))) Cos[(
        2 \[Pi])/9] - 
      s^3 (25000000000000000000000000000000 + 
         27 s (52500000000000000000000 + 
            s (41500000000000000 + 81 s (7000000 + 3 s)))) Sin[(
        2 \[Pi])/9])/(2 (6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  I6 -> (600000000 (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
         6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
         112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (1270000000000000 + 
         27 s (1900000 + s)) + 
      2500000 \[Pi] s^2 (2500000000000000 + 
         27 s^2) (10000000000000000 + 243 s (2000000 + s)) Cos[(
        2 \[Pi])/9] - 
      s^3 (2500000000000000 + 27 s^2) (10000000000000000 + 
         243 s (2000000 + s)) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
        9])/(2 (6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  I7 -> (60000000 (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
         6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
         112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (10000000000000000 + 
         243 s (2000000 + s)) + 
      2500000 \[Pi] s^2 (25000000000000000000000000000000 + 
         27 s (52500000000000000000000 + 
            s (41500000000000000 + 81 s (7000000 + 3 s)))) Cos[(
        2 \[Pi])/9] - 
      s^3 (25000000000000000000000000000000 + 
         27 s (52500000000000000000000 + 
            s (41500000000000000 + 81 s (7000000 + 3 s)))) Sin[(
        2 \[Pi])/9])/(2 (6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  I8 -> (2000000 (15 (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
           6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
           112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (10000000000000000 + 
           243 s (2000000 + s)) - 
        2500000 \[Pi] (625000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (60437500000000000000000000000000 + 
              9 s (5753125000000000000000000 + 
                 3 s (89425000000000000 + 
                    81 s (331250000 + 3 s))))) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] + 
        s (625000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (60437500000000000000000000000000 + 
              9 s (5753125000000000000000000 + 
                 3 s (89425000000000000 + 
                    81 s (331250000 + 3 s))))) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
          9]))/((6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  V1 -> (37500000 s (8000000000000000000000000000 (10000000000 + 
           967 s) - 
        135000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 (1270000000000000 + 
           27 s (1900000 + s)) + 
        3 \[Pi] s (3000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (-100000000000000000000 (-2901 + 
                 1000 Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]) + 
              3 s (-5000000000000 (-7265 + 324 Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]) + 
                 81 s (3 s - 
                    1000000 (-19 + 10 Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]))))) + 
        4 s^2 (-20000000 (306575000000000000 + 
              81 s (152000000 + 87 s)) + 
           3 s (10000000000000000 + 243 s (2000000 + s)) Sin[(
             2 \[Pi])/9])))/((6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 

              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  V2 -> -((33750000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 (1270000000000000 + 
           27 s (1900000 + s)) (2500000000000000 + 
           3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) + 
        600000000 s (-100000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (22715000000000000000000000000000 + 
              s (31965650000000000000000000 + 
                 243 s (9170000000000000 + 
                    s (2951300000 + 27 s))))) + 
        7500000 \[Pi] s^2 (10000000000000000 + 
           243 s (2000000 + s)) (-900 s (1000000 + s) + 
           2500000000000000 (-36 + Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]) + 
           3 s (1000000000 + 9 s) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]) - 
        3 s^3 (10000000000000000 + 
           243 s (2000000 + s)) (2500000000000000 + 
           3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
          9])/(20 (6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
          s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
          s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
             s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
                27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                   s (148825000000000000 + 
                    81 s (19000000 + 3 s)))))))), 
  V3 -> (3 (10000000000000000 + 
        243 s (2000000 + 
           s)) (20 (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
           6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
           112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (100000000000000 + 
           s (1000000 + s)) - 
        2500000 \[Pi] s^3 (2500000000000000 + 
           3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] + 
        s^4 (2500000000000000 + 3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
          9]))/(20 s (6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  V4 -> (s (15 (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
           6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
           112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (10000000000000000 + 
           243 s (2000000 + s)) - 
        2500000 \[Pi] (625000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (60437500000000000000000000000000 + 

              9 s (5753125000000000000000000 + 
                 3 s (89425000000000000 + 
                    81 s (331250000 + 3 s))))) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] + 
        s (625000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (60437500000000000000000000000000 + 
              9 s (5753125000000000000000000 + 
                 3 s (89425000000000000 + 
                    81 s (331250000 + 3 s))))) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
          9]))/(5 (6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  V5 -> (300000 (5000000000 + 
        243 s) (20 (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
           6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
           112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (100000000000000 + 
           s (1000000 + s)) - 
        2500000 \[Pi] s^3 (2500000000000000 + 
           3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] + 
        s^4 (2500000000000000 + 3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
          9]))/(s (6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  V6 -> (72900000 (20 (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
           6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
           112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (100000000000000 + 
           s (1000000 + s)) - 
        2500000 \[Pi] s^3 (2500000000000000 + 
           3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] + 
        s^4 (2500000000000000 + 3 s (1000000000 + 9 s)) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
          9]))/((6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s))))))), 
  V7 -> (60 (1000000 + s) (46875000000000000000000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
         6250000000000 (1360 + 81 \[Pi]^2) s^2 + 
         112500000 \[Pi] s^3 + 81 s^4) (10000000000000000 + 
         243 s (2000000 + s)) - 
      2500000 \[Pi] s (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
         3 s (72250000000000000000000000000000 + 
            3 s (22855000000000000000000000 + 
               9 s (105400000000000000 + 
                  27 s (1318000000 + 9 s))))) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] + 
      s^2 (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
         3 s (72250000000000000000000000000000 + 
            3 s (22855000000000000000000000 + 
               9 s (105400000000000000 + 
                  27 s (1318000000 + 9 s))))) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/
        9])/(20 (6250000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
        s (241750000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
           s (232112500000000000000000000000000 + 
              27 s (410200000000000000000000 + 
                 s (148825000000000000 + 81 s (19000000 + 3 s)))))))}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Jan, but could you maybe elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Carl First of all you're welcome. You asked for the s-domain expression of the current I4 (in my circuit). So in my code, I solved for it.

Comment: Yes, I can see that in your code \$I_4\$ is an expression of a lot of \$ \pi \$, and \$s\$. However, I am expected to get a single number for this problem, so is there a way to convert your expression into that? A number.

Comment: @Carl I will look at it when I have the time. Later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for your help!